# How to POST request in Swift

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift2, swifty-json

I have this API http://my-api.mydoctorfinder.com/
that will return a bool value depending on the email and password you have entered.

My problem is it will always return false despite using the correct email and password.

I was thinking that I might have not sent the right parameter since I created a dictionary containing the email and password. Then passed it on NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject method

By the way, I was using SwiftyJson.

This is my code

```
//creates a dictionary and calls the PostRequest method
func attemptLogIn( email: String, password: String) {
    let route = loggerURL
    let body: [String:String] = ["email":email, "password":password]
    makeHTTPPostRequest(route, body: body)
}

//performs post request
private func makeHTTPPostRequest(path: String, body: [String: AnyObject]) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: path)!)

    // Set the method to POST
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    do {
        // Set the POST body for the request
        let jsonBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(body, options: .PrettyPrinted)
        request.HTTPBody = jsonBody
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            if let jsonData = data {
                let json:JSON = JSON(data: jsonData)
                //onCompletion(json, nil)
                print("The Response: ")
                print(json)
            } else {
                //onCompletion(nil, error)
                print("The Response: ")
                print("Hello")
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    } catch {
        // Create your personal error
        //onCompletion(nil, nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your API documentation doesn't make it immediately obvious whether it is expecting `application/json` request, or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`  request, or XML or whatever. (And just because you might generate JSON response, it doesn't necessarily mean that the request is also JSON.) Your code suggests the request should be JSON, but if so, you should set your `Content-Type` header accordingly, as described by Josip.  By the way, you say that it "always return[s] false". What does the `response` look like? The `error`? If the parsing of the JSON failed, what did the `data` contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create JSON object using NSJSONSerialization in this way:

```
request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(body, options: [])
```

I assume that problem is in .PrettyPrinted constant.

Edit:
Also try adding correct content-type:

```
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```

Comment: Just edited the answer since the author is using Swift 2.

Answer (score 2):

The response is simply a true or false i.e. its not a json object.
So i would suggest don't use Swifty son instead use Alamofire.

Following code should work for you:-

```
let myParameters = [
    "email": "your email id",
    "password": "your password"]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://my-api.mydoctorfinder.com/ ", parameters: myParameters)
         .response { request, response, data, error in
              print(request)
              print(response)
if(response == true)
{
// do your thing
}
              print(error)
          }
```

**Note: There might be a need to typecast response to bool**

Also following is the screenshot of the link you gave, it returns true(and not a json object) [After registration, i tried to login with same credentials]

[image]

Comment: I just have one problem, even after installing Alamofire through Cocoapods, I still could not import it.

Comment: I resolved the import error, but still the same man. It's always false.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the swift post request to get data :

```
func retriveTextDataByPost(requestURL:String, params: NSDictionary, handler:((dict:NSDictionary?) -> Void)) {

    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

    let url = NSURL(string: requestURL)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.UseProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 60)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    do {
        let postData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options:NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
        request.HTTPBody = postData

        let postDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            if data != nil {

                do {

                    let dictResult:NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                    handler(dict: dictResult)

                } catch { }
            }
        }
        postDataTask.resume()

    } catch { }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Check your keys for email and password with required input for APIs
2. Check your login URL